# Another question about Tor exit node

Tags: anonymity

I read this on another question

```
Entry-Node (Knows your address and relay nodes address)
Relay-Node (knows entry-node and exit-node address)
Exit-Node (knows address of relay-node and webserver)
```

But,what if Entry-Node send my ip address to Relay-Node,which will send it to Exit-Node ?
Then will the Exit Node have both my IP Adress and what i am sending ?

In this principle it looks like the each node can send ip adresses he knows  **outside Tor** and where he get it to another nodes (like DHT) in some software or just by IP packets.

Like this

```
 Me                 Entry-Node                 Relay-Node           Exit-Node      Server
 Data(Tor) -------> -------------------------> -------------------> --------------> ----
 My IP(Tor)-------> My IP (outside Tor com.)-> -------------------> ---------My IP
 My Data            Encrypted Data             Encrypted Data       Decrypted Data
```

Well,the nodes will have to use some special kind of software...

**And one more thing,can anyone with Tor become a exit node ?**

**Or Tor accept only 'verified' entry and exit nodes,and the other can become just a relay ?**

Answer (score 1):

> But,what if Entry-Node send my ip address to Relay-Node,which will send it to Exit-Node ? Then will the Exit Node have both my IP Adress and what i am sending ?

Yes, the facts you are quoting assume the nodes are not colluding.

Generally speaking, the assumption is that while one node in your circuit may be malicious, it's very unlikely that *all* of them are, and that they're *cooperating* to compromise you. This is why it's important to have many people running nodes.

Answer (score 0):

it's *Theoretically* possible if all three nodes will have a custom software, but in standart software it's impossible